# Change heading style in latex environment

Tags: sectioning, environments, acronyms

I am using the acronym environment to list some acronyms at the beginning of a thesis I am writing. However the default heading style that acronym places doesn't match the rest of my document. I don't know lots about defining a class myself but I did this for my contributions and abstract pages

```
\newenvironment{contributions}
{\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{alwayssingle}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries Contributions}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}
```

example

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage{acronym}
\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{GE}{Giraffe Evolution} 
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

however the acronym environment does a left align heading under a line that spans the width of the page. Is there anyway to override this style to match the rest of my pages?

Cheers!

Comment: We will need information in order to help you, i.e., a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Some important information is missing, e.g., which document class you're using, how you're creating your acronyms etc. A complete MWE will provide all necessary information.

Comment: It would be useful to know what class you are using. Also, it seems you are using the ``acronym`` package, but it's not clear. Both questions would ideally be answered by a minimum working example (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since don't have enough information as to what you need, my guess is that you need the definition of alwayssingle, which can be found here  [How can I get this header and footer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42850/34618)

With that, I have the following code where I took the liberty to turn your contributions environment (into "cont" environment) to take a user-defined parameter #1 so that you can have both Contributions and Abstract environments readily available.  I also add a line under heading so that you can modify it to suit your need.

With this, you can modify it to mimic the acronym environment you want. Well, hope this is what you seek.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
 \usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}

 \makeatletter
 \newenvironment{alwayssingle}{%
 \@restonecolfalse
 \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
 \else\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
 \fi}%
 {%
 \if@restonecol\twocolumn
 \else\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\fi}
 \makeatother

 \newenvironment{cont}[1]
 {\cleardoublepage
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \begin{alwayssingle}
 \begin{center}
 \vspace*{1.5cm}
 {\Large \bfseries #1 \par \vspace{1ex}}
 {\Large This line can be changed to suit your need.\par \vspace*{1ex}}
 \end{center}
 \vspace{0.5cm}
 \begin{quote}}
 {\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

 \begin{document}
 \frontmatter
 \begin{cont}{Abstract}
 Your abstract goes here
 \end{cont}

 \begin{cont}{Contributions}
 This is where contribution begins.
 \end{cont}
 \end{document}
```

An Abstract is attached

[image]